# Basis of eigenvectors for a direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In What follows, $\mathbb{C}^{4}$ is decomposed as $\mathbb{C}^{4} = V_{+}\oplus V_{-}$, where each $V_{\pm}$ has dimension $2$.

Suppose $S$ is anoperator on $\mathbb{C}^{4}$, with eigenvalues $\pm 1/2$ and such that $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}(S\pm \frac{1}{2}) = 2$. Conside the decomposition of $S$ as a direct sum of operators $S = S_{+}\oplus S_{-}$, where $S_{\pm}$ is the restriction of $S$ to $V_{\pm}$.

Suppose we have proved that both restrictions $S_{\pm}$ have also eigenvalues $\pm 1/2$, each of multiplicity $1$. I want to prove the following fact:

*There exists an orthonormal basis of $V_{\pm}$ formed by eigenvectors of $S_{\pm}$.*

*My reasoning:* Each $V_{\pm}$ has dimension $2$, and there are two eigenvalues $\pm 1/2$ for each $S_{\pm}$, so all we need to prove is that $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}(S_{+} \pm \frac{1}{2}) = 1$ and analogously for $\operatorname{ker}(S_{-}\pm \frac{1}{2})$. If $x \in \operatorname{ker}(S\pm \frac{1}{2})$, then:
$$Sx = \mp \frac{1}{2}x \Rightarrow S(x_{1}+x_{2}) = Sx_{1}+S_{x_{2}} = S_{+}x_{1} + S_{-}x_{2} = \mp \frac{1}{2}(x_{1}+x_{2})$$
where $x_{1} \in V_{+}$ and $x_{2} = V_{-}$. Because this is a direct sum of vector subspaces, the above identity implies:
$$S_{+}x_{1} = \mp \frac{1}{2}x_{1} \quad \mbox{and} \quad S_{-}x_{2} = \mp \frac{1}{2}x_{2} $$
thus, $x_{1} \in \operatorname{ker}(S_{+}\pm \frac{1}{2})$ and $x_{2} = \operatorname{ker}(S_{-}\pm \frac{1}{2})$. Moreover, $\operatorname{ker}(S\pm \frac{1}{2}) = \operatorname{ker}(S_{+}\pm \frac{1}{2})\oplus \operatorname{ker}(S_{-}\pm \frac{1}{2})$. Since $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}(S\pm \frac{1}{2}) = 2$ and $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}(S_{\pm}\pm \frac{1}{2}) \neq 0$ (this should hold because we know $S_{\pm}$ has nonzero eigenvalues), we must have $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}(S_{\pm}\pm \frac{1}{2}) = 1$, as wished.

Is my reasoning correct?