# Why is this completeness?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

This is a second part of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4140130/basis-of-eigenvectors-and-completeness). As mentioned in the other post, I have a matrix operator $h$ on $\mathbb{C}^{4}$ and a basis of $\mathbb{C}^{4}$ formed by (orthonormal) eigenvectors $u(+)$, $u(-)$, $v(+)$ and $v(-)$ of $h$. Let me right, e.g. $u_{r}(+)$ for the $r$-th entry of the vector $u(+)$, $r=1,2,3,4$. Then, these vectors allegedly satisfy:
$$\sum_{s=\pm}[u_{r}(s)u_{r'}(s)^{*} + v_{r}(s)v_{r'}(s)^{*}] = \delta_{rr'}$$
where $u_{r}(s)^{*}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $u_{r}(s)$. This property in my book is called *completeness* of the basis, and the basis is said to be a complete orthonormal basis. But what does it have to do with completeness? Here, the term *complete* seems to be used as in the context of complete orthonormal systems in Hilbert spaces, but I see no connection with such notion of completeness and the above identity. Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition means that

$$u(+)u(+)^*+v(+)v(+)^*+u(-)u(-)^*+v(-)v(-)^*=Id_{4\times 4}.$$

Now notice that $$u(+)u(+)^*+v(+)v(+)^*+u(-)u(-)^*+v(-)v(-)^*= AA^*,$$ where
the columns of $A$ are $u(+),v(+),u(-),v(-)$.

Hence $AA^*=Id$, which means that $A$ is unitary.

So this condition means that $u(+),v(+),u(-),v(-)$ are the columns of a unitary matrix, which form an orthonormal basis of the space.

Comment: amazing answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: @MathMath You are welcome